# Authorizing the Google Drive Android API

Tags: android, permissions, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I tried to access my data in Google Drive over [Google Drive Android API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth) (not Web API). What is crazy, that when I use this access, I can access only small part of disk (just a one folder and a few files). I tried to use example code and still, result is same. Any idea what could be wrong?

**[Authorizing](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth)**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstance);

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Drive.API)
        .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

[**Reading content**](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/folders)

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    super.onConnected(connectionHint);
    Query query = new Query.Builder()
            .addFilter(Filters.or(
                    Filters.eq(SearchableField.MIME_TYPE, "text/html"),
                    Filters.eq(SearchableField.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain")))
            .build();
    Drive.DriveApi.query(getGoogleApiClient(), query).setResultCallback(metadataCallback);
}

  ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult> childrenRetrievedCallback = new
        ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(MetadataBufferResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Problem while retrieving files");
            return;
        }
        mResultsAdapter.clear();
        mResultsAdapter.append(result.getMetadataBuffer());
        showMessage("Successfully listed files.");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

As API documentation:

Note: The Google Drive Android API currently only supports `drive.file` and `drive.appfolder` authorization scopes. If your application requires additional permissions or features not yet available in the Drive Android API, you must use the Google APIs Java Client.

I think you need `drive` authorization, but this is not ready for Android API.

Comment: Thank you, I didn´t notice this. It makes this API almost useless : (

Comment: Has the status of this changed? Using the Java Client might be the way around this problem but that is a pain.