# I can't get folders that it is created by other device in New Android Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I have used new google drive android api in my project.   By the way, I can get only files and folder that i have created.
If I have created the folder and files in other device (or drive.google.com site self), I can't the files and folders.

Please check my code

```
public void loadRootFile()
{
    constant.showProgress(getActivity(), "Loading..."); 

    DriveFolder folder = Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mGoogleApiClient);
    folder.listChildren(mGoogleApiClient)
    .setResultCallback(metadataResult);

    Drive.DriveApi.requestSync(mGoogleApiClient)
    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Status result) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                // Sync not ok
                showMessage("Sync error");
                return;
            }
        }
    });

}

final private ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult> metadataResult = new
        ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(MetadataBufferResult result) {

        vGoogleList.onRefreshComplete();
        constant.hideProgress();
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Problem while retrieving files");
            return;
        }

        mGoogleList = new ArrayList<SCGoogleDrive>();           
        MetadataBuffer list = result.getMetadataBuffer();
        for(int i=0;i<list.getCount();i++)
        {
            if(!list.get(i).getTitle().equals(""))
            {
                SCGoogleDrive item = new SCGoogleDrive(list.get(i), false);
                mGoogleList.add(item);
            }
        }
        showFiles(false);
    }
};
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    constant.showProgress(mActivity, "Loading...");
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
        .addApi(Drive.API)
        .addApi(Plus.API)
        .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
        .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // required for App Folder sample
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

    constant.hideProgress();
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        // show the localized error dialog.
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), getActivity(), 0).show();
        return;
    }
    try {
        result.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    constant.hideProgress();
    showMessage("API client connected.");

    if(mIsLogout)
    {
        logoutToGoogle();
    }else
    {
        loadRootFile();
        constant.gGoogleLogin = true;
        mActivity.loginState();
        saveLoginState();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    constant.hideProgress();
    showMessage("GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
}
```

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27714031/authorizing-the-google-drive-android-api/27714094#27714094

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this line:

```
.addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
```

It specifies the only scope available in Google Drive Android API (GDAA). And it says that only the files/folders created by this (Android) app are visible.